# ¿ Como saber si el accordion está abierto o cerrado?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Estoy tratando de saber cuando el accordion este "abierto" para cambiarle a la siguiente propiedad al elemento:

```
<li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">close</i>Cerrar</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>lorem ipsum</span></div>
</li>
```

En resumen: 
Necesito que el estado inicial del accordion esté cerrado y diga en la etiqueta `<li>` "Abrir" y cuando este abierto el  accordion diga en la etiqueta `<li>` Cerrar, también cambiando los icons.

Estoy probando con lo siguiente, pero no se como determinar cuando está abierto o cerrado.

```js
 var elem = document.querySelector('.collapsible.expandable');

var instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
  accordion: false
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Blog Pablo</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h5>A demo of Expandable</h5>

        <ul class="collapsible expandable">
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">done</i>Abrir
                </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Using expandable will keep this opened unless closed by the
                        user!</span></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 
       
   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes escuchar el evento de apertura y cierre de la instancia, **onOpenEnd** y **onCloseEnd** respectivamente, y allí modificar el DOM a cómo requieres.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.collapsible.expandable');

var instance = M.Collapsible.init(elem, {
  accordion: false,
  onCloseEnd: function () {
    /************************************************************************  AQUÍ*/
    // Se cerró, cambiar a 'Abrir'
    console.log('cerrado')
  },
  onOpenEnd: function() {
    /************************************************************************ y AQUÍ*/
    // Se abrió, cambiar a 'Cerrar'
    console.log('abierto')
  }
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Blog Pablo</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h5>A demo of Expandable</h5>

        <ul class="collapsible expandable">
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">done</i>Abrir
                </div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Using expandable will keep this opened unless closed by the
                        user!</span></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 
       
   
</body>

</html>
```

En las funciones para los eventos que comentó arriba, ya sería cuestión de buscar los elementos que quieres modificar, que en este caso son **'.collapsible-header'** y **'.collapsible-body'**. Aquí sólo hay que considerar que cómo son clases si tuvieses otras estructuras con las mismas clases, y la modificación lo haces sobre el resultado del *query* a estas clases, también esas se modificarían. Puedes a) considerar usarlas con ids, o b) modificar solo las del elemento en cuestión.